# ConnectionTimeOut in AD B2C Rest API call to get Access Token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to generate access token as the output claim in the below technical profile. I am connecting to a mulesoft api endpoint(https://example.com/ct-oauth2provider-app-xyz/token) which accepts client_id and client_secret in header(client credential flow). But I am getting "*ConnectionTimeOut: An exception has occurred.*" immediately. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I referred : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#using-oauth2-bearer

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="API-AcquireAccessToken">
          <DisplayName></DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://example.com/ct-oauth2provider-app-xyz/token</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientId" />
            <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="lgk" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_secret" DefaultValue="kgf" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Is API responding with HTTP 408? Is API publicly accessbile?

Comment: Yes, the API is working good! I am able to hit the token endpoint with client_id and client_secret using postman to get the bearer token.

Comment: What does your API respond with when you send incorrect client_id + secret?

Comment: When I send it from postman, I get the response - 
{
    "access_token": "BAyd99aC-VlTCiCmMuDSWxBy-Kfps_Ixt3aylEIzJeh3JJlBSEplN7wAWN1xK02C81Ix9wZfCrMVcayB0Td8FA",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400
}

When I send it from ADB2C custom policy, I get error response - 
"Exception Message:Failed to establish connection to restful service end point within timeout limit 30 seconds. Restful service URL: https://example.com/ct-oauth2provider-app-mule/token, Exception Type:ConnectionException"

Comment: Send incorrect data in POSTMan - I suspect B2C is also sending incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it is because the certificate that bind to your example public url has expired.
The issue solved after I bind a new and updated certificate to my example site.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).